# Typoscript object variables and accessing in Fluid templates

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I have a project which has it's all templates, css, layouts and images in the folder **fileadmin/templates** .

In my layouts I have multiple links to the images present in the fileadmin/images folder and it looks kinda complex to have all the links to be referred to fileadmin/images.

```
Example : 
src="fileadmin/images/dog.jpg"
src="fileadmin/images/cat.jpg"
src="fileadmin/images/monkey.jpg"
```

Instead of doing this can I assign a object in the typoscript (..in the template) like

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10{
variables{
    paths.images=fileadmin/images
    paths.css=fileadmin/css
    paths.js=fileadmin/js
}
}
```

and access this from the HTML pages as

```
src="{paths.images}/cat.jgp"
src="{paths.js}/close.js"
```

I am using Typo3 version 6.0.4.

Comment: You could, but not with a dot in the variable name as this is reserved for array access.

Comment: So I should declare 3 different variables for each path ? 
I was thinking if can declare an object called Path and its variables as image, css and js and assign values respectively .. Is that a possible solution ?

If you can, can you please throw in some code here? 

Thanks

Comment: ``TypoScript`` does not know about objects. ``TypoScript``is a nested PHP array that keys evaluated with some foreach loops and case statements. You could use names like ``pathImages, pathCss, pathJs``.

Comment: Oh.. okay. Thanks for the help :) 
Also, I had another doubt, Can I declare arrays here in TypoScript and use them in the FLUID templates ?

Comment: No, ``TypoScript`` does not know arrays, but only strings.

Comment: @pgampe I think you should summarize your comments in an answer and then RaD0 could close this question too. You wrote a correct answer, may it will help in the future for someone else too! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `pathImages`, `pathCss` and `pathJs`.

`TypoScript` does not know about arrays and there is no way to return an array via `TypoScript`. `TypoScript` is transformed into a PHP array by separation it at the dots and then it is rendered via multiple `foreach` loops. Only strings are returned as a result of this process.